# Azure Quota Update API is showing 'in progress'

Tags: azure, quota, azure-rest-api

I've tried increasing our Azure Quota limit using the [Quota Update API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/reserved-vm-instances/quota/update). It says that the request is being processed but nothing happened after so many hours. It doesn't have any error so not sure what is wrong with my API call.

Here is my code via Ansible:

```
    - name: Quota Increase
  azure.azcollection.azure_rm_resource:
    client_id: "{{ az_client_id }}"
    secret: "{{ az_secret }}"
    tenant: "{{ az_tenant_id }}"
    subscription_id: "{{ az_subscription_id }}"
    method: PATCH
    url: "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{{ az_subscription_id }}/providers/Microsoft.Capacity/resourceProviders/Microsoft.Compute/locations/{{ az_environment }}/serviceLimits/{{ vm_family_series }}?api-version=2020-10-25"
    body:
      properties:
        limit: 352
        unit: "Count"
        name:
          value: "{{ vm_family_series }}"
  register: _result
- name: Display _result
  debug:
    msg: "{{ _result }}"
```

Here is the result of the code when I try to display it:

```
{
"msg": {
    "changed": true,
    "response": {
        "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Capacity/resourceProviders/Microsoft.Compute/locations/westus/serviceLimitsRequests/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "name": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "properties": {
            "message": "Request processing.",
            "provisioningState": "InProgress",
            "properties": {
                "properties": {
                    "currentValue": 0,
                    "limit": 352,
                    "name": {
                        "value": "STANDARDDV3FAMILY"
                    },
                    "properties": {},
                    "provisioningState": "InProgress"
                }
            }
        },
        "type": "Microsoft.Capacity/ServiceLimits"
    },
    "warnings": [
        "Azure API profile latest does not define an entry for GenericRestClient"
    ],
    "failed": false
},
"_ansible_verbose_always": true,
"_ansible_no_log": false,
"changed": false
```

}

Comment: Have tried checking the quota request status using this rest api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/reserved-vm-instances/quota-request-status/get#quotarequestinprogress

Comment: I just checked the status and it seems like it failed. Not sure why

Comment: You can look at the activity logs for that particular operation `create resource service limit ` under your subscription as shown in this [image](https://i.imgur.com/4pPtb2y.png)  to know why the operation has failed.